# Drop down dynamic

Tags: php, ajax

I have seen it but dont know how to achieve it.
The idea is that I have a drop down menu and when something is selected, something else will appear. Is it AJAX?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is Javascript.

Comment: Although it could make use of ajax to get the content for the "something else"...

Comment: Could be AJAX as well, depends if the "something else" that appears is loaded asynchronously or not.

Comment: While it might not be a 'complete answer', I feel obligated to point out the difference between Javascript/jQuery/AJAX. For some reason they all get smashed together.